# Добрый день, помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в CSS

Tags: css

помогите пожалуйста разобраться, заголовок Метод Феймана не отображается двумя слившимися буквами, подзаголовок Выучить и не забыть не в центре,
в чем я ошибку в CSS сделал, не пойму. В песочнице мой код https://jsfiddle.net/57akz24f/

```css
.feinman {
    position: relative;
    height: 690px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.feiman_column {
    width: 648px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.feiman_title {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 648px;
    line-height: 1.15px;
    font-size: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 1;
}

.feiman_subtitle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 79px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    line-height: 51px;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: normal;
    z-index: 2;
}

.feiman_link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 48px;
    line-height: 51px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none
}

.feiman_img {
    width: 867px;
    height: 637px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="feinman ">
        <div class="feiman_column">
            <h2 class="feiman_title">Метод Феймана
            </h2>
            <h4 class="feiman_subtitle">Выучить и не забыть.
            </h4>
        </div>
        <a href="https://naruto.wiki/Заглавная_страница" class="feiman_link">Подробнее →</a > 
        
        <img class="feinman_img" src="imag/feynman.png" alt="Фейман"></img>



    </section>
```

Comment: Можете еще залить и html для полной картины

Comment: тут вы много чего добавили но а смысл добавленных свойств знаете?
для центрирования абсолютного блока я знаю такой подход left: 50% ; transform: translateX(-50%) и он будет центрироватся в блоке feiman_column

Comment: CSS код в первом блоке залит, html во втором залит

Comment: @ВаняМеркулов про первую часть вопроса мне лично не понятно если можно по другому перефразируйте

Comment: Проблема в line-height для .feiman_title) + старайтесь обходить стороной фиксированные ширины и высоты)